# Not getting the updated pathname value inside the eventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

I'm adding a scroll event listener to the effect, so that when a certain section is reached, the url changes to a different one.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  };
}, [])
```

Here's the function `handleScroll`

```
const handleScroll = () => {
  const urlKey = `/${section}/${url}`;

  if (pathname !== urlKey) {
    history.replace(urlKey);
  }
}
```

The values for `section` and `url` are taken elsewhere, and they are output correctly. The problem is that inside `handleScroll` `pathname` is always the same. I don't understand how to fix it. Please give me a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap the `handleScroll` function in `useCallback`, which will create a new instance of the function whenever one of the dependencies (`section`, `url`, `pathname`) changes:

```js
const handleScroll = React.useCallback(
  () => {
    const urlKey = `/${section}/${url}`;

    if (pathname !== urlKey) {
      history.replace(urlKey);
  },
  [section, url, pathname]
);
```

Then, add the callback to the dependencies of `useEffect` to update the event listener whenever there is a new instance of `handleScroll`:

```js
React.useEffect(
  () => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, 
  [handleScroll]
);
```